# Intercept function call that returns an Observable to show the loading indicator

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

In my Angular application sometimes I need to block UI while some HTTP requests are running and I want to achieve this via such (or similar) API

```
userService.block(elementId).getUser().subscribe();
```

I want components to decide when and what should be blocked and functions inside service to be independent of this blocking mechanism.

Right now I have to do something like

```
blockService.block(elementId);
userService.getUser().subscribe(()=>blockService.unBlock(elementId));
```

I don't want to use HttpInterceptor here as in this case I will need to update my functions to mark request calls as blockable (for example a custom header with element selector) to filter them inside interceptor.

I succeeded in the implementation based on ES6 proxies. I created a base class for my services that has block function. But, but always IE - it will not work on IE11.
Draft implementation:

```
block(selector: string) {
    return new Proxy(this, {
      get: (target, propKey) => {
        let member = target[propKey];

        return (...args) => {
          this.blockService.blockUi(selector);
          let result = member.apply(target, args);

          result.subscribe(() => target.blockService.unblockUi(selector));
          return result;
        };
      }
    });
  }
```

Any ideas how to do it without Proxy?

PS. The way with a function wrapper doesn't look nice:

```
blockService.block(userService.getUser).subscribe()
```

but if I don't find the fluent way I will have to use it.

Comment: The proxy solution doesn't work as intended. I don't see any advantage over what you do right now. If anything then a custom operator would be the best choice imho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do it though extending Observable's prototype (API is a little bit different from the question but the idea is the same - no need to call something twice before and after).

TypeScript implementation (for plaine JS you don't need module declaration):

```
declare module 'rxjs/Observable' {
  interface Observable<T> {
    block(blockService: UiBlockerService, elementId?: string): Observable<T>;
  }
}

Observable.prototype.blockUi = function <T>(blockService: UiBlockerService, elementId?: string) {
  blockService.block(elementId);
  const observable = this as Observable<T>;

  return observable.pipe(finalize(() => blockService.unblockUi(elementId)));
};
```

Usage:

```
userService.getUser().block(uiBlocker, elementId).subscribe();
```

It's important to call `block()` after the operators (map, tap, etc) if you want to block/show a spinner while they are processing data from the Observable.